# Chart.js data set static numbers

Tags: javascript, chart.js

how to make the Y-axis have static values, even if the graph is not drawn.  I need to always have 4 values ​​`0, 5, 10, 15`, even if there is no graph. This is an updatable chart.

This is my chart

[image]

**I need like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ca be achieved by defining the y-axis as follows:

```
y: {
  suggestedMin: 0,
  suggestedMax: 15,
  ticks: {
    stepSize: 5
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [,,]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        suggestedMin: 0,
        suggestedMax: 15,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```